# How to show modal box whenever choose the select option using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap to show modal box. When the user chooses the select option value I just call the jQuery to show the specific modal box.

**Like below:**

```
$(document).on('change','#apply',function () {
   if($(this).val() == 1 ) {
      $('#update').modal("show");
   } else if ( $(this).val() == 2 ) {
      $('#delete_ticket_booking').modal("show");
   }
});
```

**The HTML code of select looks like this:**

```
<select name="apply" class="form-control full-width" id="apply">
<option value="">--Action--</option>
<option value="1">Confirm</option>
<option value="2">Delete</option>
</select>
```

Now, **for example:** when the user chooses the **confirm** option it's showing the confirm modal box.

Again If the user chooses the **confirm** option then it's showing nothing.

I need to show that modal box again when user click on the **confirm** option!

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you want to have a modal box that lets you confirm or cancel a booking. is that correct?

Comment: the full code is working fine. I just want to show any modal box again when clicking on the options again and again.

Comment: for example: I select confirm it will show me confirm modal box. I close this modal box. Again I want to show this confirm modal box but I can't. I need to show modal box again!

Comment: @imtheman Maybe that's the solution I am looking for :)

Comment: I understand what you're looking for, but I'm wondering if you decided to use a select box because you couldn't get a custom confirm box working, and would prefer a custom confirm modal box if you could make one.